# Android. Espresso: can't check background

Tags: android-espresso

Windows 10 (64 bit),
Android Studio 3.1.2,
Gradle 4.4, Java 1.8.

Here my layout xml

```xml
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/loginTextView"
    android:layout_width="255dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:background="@drawable/sign_in_login_bg"
    android:gravity="center"                              
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/registerTextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Here **@drawable/sign_in_login_bg**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/color_primary" />
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/text_view_rounded_corner_radius" />
</shape>
```

I want to write espresso test that check that **loginTextView** has background **@drawable/sign_in_login_bg**

So I write custom matcher:

```java
import org.hamcrest.Matcher;
public static Matcher<View> withBackground(final int expectedResourceId) {
        
      return new BoundedMatcher<View, View>(View.class) {
        
          @Override
          public boolean matchesSafely(View view) {
              return sameBitmap(view.getContext(), view.getBackground(), expectedResourceId);
         }
        
         @Override
         public void describeTo(Description description) {
             description.appendText("has background resource " + expectedResourceId);
        }
    };
}
```

Here method **sameBitmap**:

```java
private static boolean sameBitmap(Context context, Drawable drawable, int expectedId) {
    Drawable expectedDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, expectedId);
    if (drawable == null || expectedDrawable == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (drawable instanceof StateListDrawable && expectedDrawable instanceof StateListDrawable) {
        drawable = drawable.getCurrent();
        expectedDrawable = expectedDrawable.getCurrent();
    }
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap otherBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) expectedDrawable).getBitmap();
        return bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here my espresso test:

```java
@Test
public void loginTextViewBackground() {
 
 
 
 onView(withId(R.id.loginTextView)).check(matches(withBackground(R.drawable.sign_in_login_bg)));
}
```

But I get error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'has background resource 2131230909' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: has background resource 2131230909
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131296429, res-name=loginTextView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=765, height=180, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@bcce82, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=158.0, y=1283.0, text=Login, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:580)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:90)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:52)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:314)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:291)
at com.myproject.android.activity.SignInActivityTest.loginTextViewBackground(SignInActivityTest.java:158)

at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1879)
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 'has background resource 2131230909' doesn't match the selected view.
Expected: has background resource 2131230909
Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=2131296429, res-name=loginTextView, visibility=VISIBLE, width=765, height=180, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=true, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, layout-params=android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams@bcce82, tag=null, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=158.0, y=1283.0, text=Login, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"

at android.support.test.espresso.matcher.ViewMatchers.assertThat(ViewMatchers.java:526)
```

Comment: Where's your sameBitmap method defined?

Comment: I update my post.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As your drawable is a GradientDrawable it must be handled in your Matcher as well. So, your matcher could look like below:

```
private static boolean sameBitmap(Context context, Drawable drawable, int expectedId) {
    Drawable expectedDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, expectedId);
    if (drawable == null || expectedDrawable == null) {
        return false;
    }

    if (drawable instanceof StateListDrawable && expectedDrawable instanceof StateListDrawable) {
        drawable = drawable.getCurrent();
        expectedDrawable = expectedDrawable.getCurrent();
    }
    if (drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable) {
        Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
        Bitmap otherBitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) expectedDrawable).getBitmap();
        return bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap);
    }

    if (drawable instanceof VectorDrawable ||
            drawable instanceof VectorDrawableCompat ||
            drawable instanceof GradientDrawable) {
        Rect drawableRect = drawable.getBounds();
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawableRect.width(), drawableRect.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        Bitmap otherBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawableRect.width(), drawableRect.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas otherCanvas = new Canvas(otherBitmap);
        expectedDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, otherCanvas.getWidth(), otherCanvas.getHeight());
        expectedDrawable.draw(otherCanvas);
        return bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Improving a little bit Anatolii's answer, first we must define the custom matcher:

```
fun withBackground(expectedResourceId: Int): Matcher<View?>? {
        return object : BoundedMatcher<View?, View>(View::class.java) {
            override fun matchesSafely(view: View): Boolean {
                return sameBitmap(view.context, view.background, expectedResourceId)
            }

            override fun describeTo(description: Description) {
                description.appendText("has background resource $expectedResourceId")
            }
        }
    }
```

Secondly, private method *sameBitmap* taking into consideration all the different alternatives and checking both drawables type:

```
private fun sameBitmap(context: Context, drawable: Drawable, resourceId: Int): Boolean {
        var drawable: Drawable? = drawable
        var expectedDrawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resourceId)
        if (drawable == null || expectedDrawable == null) {
            return false
        }

        if (drawable is StateListDrawable && expectedDrawable is StateListDrawable) {
            drawable = drawable.getCurrent()
            expectedDrawable = expectedDrawable.getCurrent()
        }

        if (drawable is BitmapDrawable) {
            val bitmap = drawable.bitmap
            val otherBitmap = (expectedDrawable as BitmapDrawable).bitmap
            return bitmap.sameAs(otherBitmap)
        }

        if(currentDrawable is ColorDrawable && expectedDrawable is ColorDrawable) {
            val expectedColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, resourceId)
            return currentDrawable.color == expectedColor
        }

        if ((drawable is VectorDrawable && expectedDrawable is VectorDrawable) || (drawable is VectorDrawableCompat && expectedDrawable is VectorDrawableCompat) || (drawable is GradientDrawable && expectedDrawable is GradientDrawable)) {
            return drawableToBitmap(drawable.current)!!.sameAs(drawableToBitmap(expectedDrawable.current))
        }
        return false
    }
```

And finally *drawableToBitmap* method:

```
private fun drawableToBitmap(drawable: Drawable): Bitmap? {
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        if (drawable is BitmapDrawable) {
            if (drawable.bitmap != null) {
                return drawable.bitmap
            }
        }
        bitmap = if (drawable.intrinsicWidth <= 0 || drawable.intrinsicHeight <= 0) {
            Bitmap.createBitmap(1,
                1,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888) // Single color bitmap will be created of 1x1 pixel
        } else {
            Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.intrinsicWidth,
                drawable.intrinsicHeight,
                Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
        }
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }
```

And this is the way to use it:

```
onView(withId(R.id.on_boarding_initial_circle)).check(matches(withBackground(R.drawable.bg_gray_circle)))
onView(withId(R.id.on_boarding_initial_circle)).check(matches(withBackground(R.color.color_primary)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: [HasBackgroundMatcher](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/matcher/HasBackgroundMatcher)

```
onView(allOf(withId(R.id. loginTextView),
               hasBackground(R.drawable. sign_in_login_bg), isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: This cannot check for backgrounds with color resources contrary to @carlos-daniel answer which I edited to make it possible.